# cannot display phpinfo() call on nginx server

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Local host shows 'engine x welcome' page instead of `phpinfo()` call on ubuntu 16.04 lts, even though I have configured `php.ini` file. On opening localhost/index.php download link appears.

Comment: show us your nginx "server" config i mean what is your root or did u configured php-fpm? needed more info about nginx rather than php

Comment: how can i show you my nginx server info? i am  novice

Comment: Are there any file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` in this directory ?

Comment: no it is empty.

Comment: Ok, this means that you dont configured any domain/server to your nginx it has only his default server path please check [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx) or google it how to configure nginx web server

Answer (score 1):

Any good configuration will likely include "[disable_functions = phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)" in the php.ini file.

I'm confused as to why you are getting a "download" link, however. That most-often indicates that you have an improperly set MIME-type. (eg. your server doesn't know how to handle a PHP file - so it sets it to application/octet-stream and your web browser, also not knowing how to handle it, will just download it)